# impossible to html parsing facebook public profile with php

Tags: php, html, facebook, parsing

i grabbed an html from this url : http://facebook.com/zuck
there is no problem to echo it to the client browser but i found it impossible to parse it with php.

i am trying to parse the text inside div tags for example :

```
preg_match_all("/<div class=\"mediaPageName\">(.*)<\/div>/",$html,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

returns empty array
i also tried with DOMDocument and with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser both of them return empty elements and can't grab the text of the html.

how is it even possible?
there is a solution to that?

Comment: Scraping is probably a ToS violation.  You're better off with graph API when possible: http://graph.facebook.com/zuck

Comment: @Frank Farmer Maybe true, but it is ironic worrying about ToS violations with Facebook, considering all of their privacy issues.

Comment: Is he trying to [parse HTML using a regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$html = str_replace(array('\u003c','\"','\/'), array('<','"','/'), $html);
preg_match_all('/<div class=\"mediaPageName\">(.*?)<\/div>/', $html, $matches); 
var_dump($matches);
```

must be a way to do it with one single line of preg_match instead of the code above and also grab this tag `<span class="fwb">text</span>`, but i don't know how to write it in a single line.

Answer (score 3):

It is quite possible.

Easiest way is to load the complete DOM into DOMDocument or [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/)

**Edit:**

From looking at the source code of the link provided, the element you are searching for is replacing less than characters, `<` with the unicode representation: `\u003c`.

Example: `\u003cdiv class=\"mediaPageName\">Nirvana\u003c\/div>`

**Edit 2:**
As mentioned by others, do not parse HTML when not necessary. But it looks like this is required in this case as Frank Farmer mentions.

This regex will find some matches (only one per line, hopefully someone can adjust it to get all the matches).
`preg_match_all('%\\\\u003cdiv class=.*mediaPageName[^>]*>([^>]*)\\\\u003c%i', $html, $matches);`

It may be worthwhile finding out how to use Unicode regex as outlined [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

Comment: @Brad F Jacobs I see that, but it does not mean that it is not the correct solution - it could easily be done with DOMDocument.

Comment: @brian_d even when i do only `preg_match('/mediaPageName/',$html)` it returns false, but i checked with echo and i can see it with my eyes the div element with the class mediaPageName. i don't understand.

Comment: @brian_d i tried to load it to DOMDocument it is not working.

Comment: @Ben preg_match should return a number and false only on an error. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php. You need pattern delimeters - ex) '/mediaPageName/'

Comment: @Ben to make sure, is `var_dump(preg_match('/mediaPageName/', $html))` 0 or false? And are you sure `$html` is not empty?

Comment: @brian_d `preg_match_all('/<div class="mediaPageName">(.*)<\/div>/', $html,$matches);
var_dump($matches);` returns `array(2) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> array(0) { } }` and `echo $html` returns all the html correctly

Comment: @Ben look at my updated answer, it looks like the divs you are looking for have the `<` signs output in unicode `\u003c`

Comment: @brian_d you right! so what is the correct regex to grab it? i tried `preg_match_all('/\\u003cdiv class=\\"mediaPageName\\">(.*)\\u003c\\\/div>/', $html,$matches); var_dump($matches);` not working.

Comment: The unicode `\u003c` issue is related to the fact that the markup in question is actually part of what looks like a JSON-encoded string wrapped in a <script> tag.  That'll make parsing this with DOM tricky -- the tag doesn't actually exist in the page's DOM as true, distinct element.  The only DOM element containing this markup is the `<script>` tag itself.

Comment: @Ben I have added another edit with a partial solution - it gets some results, but misses others.

Comment: @brian_d I figured it out. i just convert the unicode to html with this code `$html = str_replace(array('\u003c','\"','\/'), array('<','"','/'), $html);` then i will get $html with `<div class="mediaPageName">Minimalism</div>` on this data i run this code `preg_match_all('/<div class=\"mediaPageName\">(.*?)<\/div>/', $html, $matches);
var_dump($matches);` and done. this is my best solution. i know that must be a way to do it with a single preg_match line. i will work on it. thanks alot! next step is to preg_match the other divs by figuring out the structure of all the elements in the page.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably going to be much better off in the long run if you just use the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/). The profile picture and some basic account information is public and requires no authentication or authorization. Just issue a request for `http://graph.facebook.com/zuck/picture` for example.

Comment: i got it but i cant get all the data that i need from the graph api. there is a solution to my problem?

Comment: The solution is to say "oh well". Screen scraping Facebook is going to end in tears eventually.